# Any react.js snippet plugin to install for Netbeans 12?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins, netbeans-12

I just installed Netbeans 12 and I am diving into react.js. I was wondering if a react snippet plugin exists? Just as for visual studio (React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets)?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences -> Editor -> Code Templates

You can create as many of these as you like for the supported languages.  Just press tab after the keys.  For example simply typing in "ae" + [TAB] on your keyboard will produce the following code snippet:

```
afterEach(function () {
   
});
```

[image: Netbeans snippet help - no plugin necessary]